# What sequence of Git commands could have resulted in this commit graph

Tags: git, commit

What sequence of Git commands could have resulted in this commit graph in the below image?

[image]

Comment: Simplest possible branch and merge. What’s the hard part?

Comment: This is an interview question and i need the answer to be the best, i already did the commands but i need to make sure all are right with the best minds here

Comment: No, you don't. If it's an interview question, all you need to do is explain it. No "best", no "perfect", git is a tool, and the way it works is pretty "dumb" in that there's only a handful of operations it can perform. So: what order of operations are we seeing here? branch, work on code, commit, merge, done.

Answer (score 2):

Two first commits:

- [edit]
- `git commit`
- [edit]
- `git commit`

Then create a branch

- `git checkout -b feature-branch`

Edit and create a commit

- [edit]
- `git commit`

Come back to the master branch:

- `git checkout master`

Edit and do a commit:

- [edit]
- `git commit`

Then merge

- `git merge feture-branch`

And finaly:

- [edit]
- `git commit`

Answer (score 1):

When master was on third and feature branch already had its commit:

```
git checkout --detach master
git merge feature-branch -m "merge"
# do changes
git add .
git commit -m "fourth commit"
```

There you go.

Comment: Oh I see. No, you’re taking the diagram too literally. The diagram is as bad as the question. The whole chain is being labeled as master!

Comment: Well... the chart has the two branches and HEAD in separate points so..... anyway

Comment: Yeah, I think it’s just a shoddy chart. It just means all 5 lower commits are the master branch, even though you and I know that’s bogus.

Answer (score -1):

This is my answer:

```
#edit or add something
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
#edit or add something
git add .
git commit -m "second commit"
git checkout feature-branch
#add an awesome feature
git add .
git commit -m "awesome-feature"
git merge feature-branch -m "merge"
git checkout master
#edit or add something
git add .
git commit -m "third commit"
#edit or add something
git add .
git commit -m "fourth commit"
```

Comment: AT the point of checkout to feature-branch this is the syntax
`git checkout -b feature-branch`